# Refreshing feed on 0.1.76 causes crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I try to refresh my feed on the Android application, it shows the 'Loading' animation for a second, stops the animation. After another few seconds, the application crashes.

It appears to be a ClassCastException within `BannerAdFeedItem.java`

*Android 4.3, 0.1.76*

Comment: Loading the different sites individually (Stack Overflow, MSO, etc.) works properly.

Comment: v0.1.77 is available in the play store, and I can't reproduce it on that version.

Comment: I just updated, and I can't reproduce it either. I'll flag my question as non-reproducable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are correct here, that was something we added to the feed in the back-end before version 0.1.77 shipped out. The app forces you to update if you're too far behind so we're not too worried about making our additions past-proof at the moment, sorry about that.

Comment: Gotcha (and especially with it being an alpha, there's not much of a need for backwards-compatibility). Cheers! Would it be [status-norepro] or [status-declined] (or heck, [status-completed])?

Comment: I think [status-completed] is technically correct (the best type of correct)